# Retrieve ics file from download link through code (Go)

Tags: file, go, http, request, icalendar

I'm trying to make a .ics file parser, and my first step to achieve this goal is to retrieve my .ics file from the download link. Unfortunately I cannot get any data.

I'm coding in Go and here is how I'm doing things for now :

```
ical, err = http.Get(link.Value)
checkErr(err)

fmt.Println(ical.Status)
fmt.Println(ical.ContentLength)

_, err = os.OpenFile("calendar.ics", os.O_CREATE, os.ModePerm)
checkErr(err)

var calendarData []byte

_, err = ical.Body.Read(calendarData)
checkErr(err)

os.WriteFile("calendar.ics", calendarData, fs.FileMode(os.O_WRONLY))
```

After running that code, there is a "calendar.ics" created but it's still empty.

I don't understand why it doesn't work because :

- the status code is 200 OK
- if I use `curl "mylink" > calendar.ics` it's working which should mean there is no specific "security" to access those data

Hoping someone can help me soon ! :)

PS: `checkErr()` is just a simple `if err != nil { log.Fatalln(err) }`

Comment: `http.Get(link.Value)`: Good.  SUGGESTED CHANGES/ADDITIONS: `file, err := os.Create(fileName)`, `size, err := io.Copy(file, ical.Body)`, etc.  Q: Was that soon enough ;)?

Comment: yup, very fast and very efficient everything is working now, but can you tell me why the ical.Body.Read([]byte) wasn't working ?

Comment: You are reading 0 bytes into an empty slice, so there are 0 bytes to write to the file. If you want to read the whole body, there is `io.ReadAll`. (you should of course be closing the body and checking `WriteFile` for errors too)